# Need info on string functions in sql

Tags: sql

Could you please help me on this scenario

'Hello World'

i want to print like 'ello World'

what are the possible diff ways to acheive this

Comment: SQL itself has no "print". Which dbms are you using? (Many products have their own string functions.)

Comment: Do you want to get rid och the first character? Only if it's H? Or all H?

Comment: sorry i want to get record like "ello World" and my input is "Hello World"

Comment: yes only first letter i want to remove

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select substr('Hello World',2) from dual;--Oracle
select substr('Hello World',2);--Mysql
select substring('Hello World',2)--Postgres
```

Comment: thanks but In sql server without using substring , is any other option available

Comment: You can use Right(String,number of characters)

Comment: ANSI SQL: `substring('Hello World' from 2)`.